# Capistrano deploy error while deploying to Ubuntu server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, devops

I was following this [blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma#), to set up my rails server, and after I ran this command, I am getting the following error

```
cap production deploy:initial --trace


cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 104.197.138.17: connection closed by remote host
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:16:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Net::SSH::Disconnect: connection closed by remote host
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:50:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in negotiate!'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in negotiate!'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:45:in `loop'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:45:in `block in negotiate!'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:43:in `loop'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:43:in `negotiate!'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:32:in `initialize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `new'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `block in initialize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:75:in `timeout'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:126:in `timeout'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `initialize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:207:in `new'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:207:in `start'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:187:in `with_ssh'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:137:in `block in _execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `tap'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `_execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:62:in `test'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
EOFError: end of file reached
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:47:in `readpartial'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in negotiate!'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:45:in `loop'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:45:in `block in negotiate!'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:43:in `loop'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:43:in `negotiate!'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:32:in `initialize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `new'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `block in initialize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:75:in `timeout'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:126:in `timeout'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `initialize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:207:in `new'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:207:in `start'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:187:in `with_ssh'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:137:in `block in _execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `tap'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `_execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:62:in `test'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook
```

Comment: Can you SSH into your server? `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa deploy@104.197.138.17` ?

Comment: yes, I am able to log in to the server.

Comment: What about when you run `cap production deploy:check`?  Same thing?

Comment: you are right, same error after I ran that command

Comment: Any progress with this one? I'm getting the same error...

Comment: Yes, please see the last answer below, you must comment out one of the lines in your deploy.rb file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in my deploy.rb file which is generated by Capistrano, I commented out 
this line. And it started to work.

```
set :ssh_options,{ forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
```

Comment: Yeah it works. Can I ask the reason why?

Answer (score 1):

It appears Capistrano can't connect to the server and is timing out, the most likely culprit is that it's not reading the SSH key correctly.  The easiest way to test it would be to try creating an ssh config file:

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

Add:

```
Host 104.197.138.17
    HostName 104.197.138.17
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Try:

```
ssh deploy@104.197.138.17
```

Make sure it connects.  (I'm assuming 104.197.138.17 is the IP of your server...)

If that works, try `cap production deploy:check` again.

--

What's happening here is the ssh config will feed the extra parameters to any SSH call to that Host (in this case the IP).  You could change the Host to 'mysite.com' if you wanted and then you would run `ssh deploy@mysite.com` if you wanted to create some separation.  Digital Ocean [has tutorial about it](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-custom-connection-options-for-your-ssh-client).

Comment: I am able to ssh without adding anything to ~/.ssh/config file. I am not sure how that is going to help me. Anyhow, I tried doing what you suggested, still same issue.