# Deploying Rails-application on Ubuntu server using Capistrano gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, ssh

I try to deploy my rails application on local virtual machine which runs ubuntu 14 LTS. I use nginx and phusion passenger. Also, I use capistrano gem for deployment.

I added my local ssh key to virtual machine's authorized keys.
Also i have no problem connecting to my virtual machine via ssh like that:
ssh neil@192.168.0.8

However when I write:

```
bundle exec cap production deploy
```

I get the following error:

```
cap aborted!

Net::SSH::Disconnect: connection closed by remote host

EOFError: end of file reached

Tasks: TOP => rbenv:validate
```

**My deploy.rb file:**

```
server "192.168.0.8", port: 80, roles: %i(:web :app :db), primary: true  
set :log_level, :debug  

set :application, "mySimpleBlog"  
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:NeilAlishev/mySimpleBlog.git"  
set :user,            "neil"  
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push("config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml")  
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push("log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets",
  "vendor/bundle", "public/system", "public/uploads")  
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/src/#{fetch(:application)}"  

set :rbenv_type, :user  
set :rbenv_ruby, "2.2.4"  
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} "\
  "RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"  
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w(rake gem bundle ruby rails)  
set :rbenv_roles, :all  

namespace :deploy do  
  desc "Restart application"  
  task :restart do  
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do  
      execute :touch, release_path.join("tmp/restart.txt")  
    end  
  end  

  after :publishing, "deploy:restart"  
  after :finishing, "deploy:cleanup"  
end
```

**My deploy/production.rb file:**

```
set :stage, :production  
server "192.168.0.8", user: "neil", roles: %w(web app db)  
role :app, %w(neil@192.168.0.8)  
role :web, %w(neil@192.168.0.8)  
role :db,  %w(neil@192.168.0.8)
```

**My nginx.conf file:**

```
server {  
listen 80;  
server_name 192.168.0.8;  
charset utf-8;  
rails_env production;  
passenger_enabled on;  
root /home/neil/mySimpleBlog/current/public;  
}
```

Comment: Can you try the solutions in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567498/capistrano-deploy-error-while-deploying-to-ubuntu-server)?

Comment: Are you sure you're able to to SSH into the targeting server?

Comment: When i just type 
ssh neil@address_of_the_server 
i access the server without any problem.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same problem. I can connect to the machine but have same error with you when `cap production deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Change production.rb like this,

```
role :app, 'address_of_the_server', {
:ssh_options => {
:keys => 'key_path(like ~/.ssh/key_name.pem)'
 }
}

role :web, 'address_of_the_server', {
 :ssh_options => {
:keys => 'key_path(like ~/.ssh/key_name.pem)'
 }
}

role :db, 'address_of_the_server', {
 :ssh_options => {
   :keys => 'key_path(like ~/.ssh/key_name.pem)'
 }
}
```